# A plain-text & single-line contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I am trying to make a “single-line” and “plain-text” `contenteditable` div. In other words, I just want to make a `<input type="text">`, but not present in this form. How can I use the form of `contenteditable` `div` to present the form of `<input type="text">`?

Comment: give some height and width to the div, may be?

Comment: So you want a div that looks like an input type=text ?

Comment: Yeah, a single-line-and-plain-text contenteditable div. It looks like a  “<input type="text">”, but not.

Comment: Try:

<div style="height:20px; width:80px; border:1px solid black; overflow:auto" contenteditable = true> </div>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could disable <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for the `contentEditable` element using JavaScript. Here is a jQuery version:

```js
$('[contenteditable]').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Submit the form, etc.
  }
})
.on('paste keyup', function () {
  var _this = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    // remove the markups
    $(_this).html($(_this).text());
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] * {
  display: none; /* hide all descendants */
}

[contenteditable] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;

  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;

  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable>
    blah blah blah...
</div>
```

Comment: But there still a problem: how can I strip the HTML tags?

Comment: @RedWhale It can be done by replacing the content of the element with the text nodes. In plain JavaScript, there's `element.textContent` that can get/set the text content of an element. The jQuery version is `.text()`.

Comment: the content is not scrollable - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: @4esn0k This is what "single-line" means, isn't it?

Comment: horizontal scrolling could be useful for "single-line"

Comment: @4esn0k True, but the goal was to present the form of a text input which does not have a scrollbar ui naturally.

Comment: the <input> is still scrollable when you are trying to select some text or when doing "drag and drop"

Comment: @4esn0k Oh, I got the point. That's right. I didn't think of it at the time of writing.